# What is The Appropriate Data Structure For Modifying Some Elements of a Collection In Place?

Tags: java, data-structures

Say I have a collection of objects, and for every object that has a certain property,I would like to remove that object and insert a new object in its place. As an example lets say I have   a collection of animal objects:

[Dog, Dog, Dog, Coyote, Dog, Fox, Dog, Cat, Ferret, Groundhog]

```
for each animal -> 
   if animal = Dog, Ferret, Groundhog continue iterating
   else if animal = Coyote, replace with Dog and continue iterating
   else if animal = Fox, replace with Dog and continue iterating
```

Which data structure would be the best for accomplishing something like this while maintaining the initial order of the collection? Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: a usual array, with the size doubled whenever no slot is available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An array is the most light-weight data structure you can use and most appropriate if the number of elements does not change. The only issue is that you must declare the reference type of the array to all be equal. I would suggest all the classes extend from a parent class, say 'Animal'.
In the solution below, I have extended all the classes from Animal:

```
class Animal{

}
class Dog extends Animal{

}
class Cat extends Animal{

}
class Coyote extends Animal{

}
class Fox extends Animal{

}
class Ferret extends Animal{

}
class Groundhog extends Animal{

}
```

I have then used an array to store the Animal instances.
A for-loop will then iterate through each item and replace the instances of Fox and Coyote with Dog.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Dog a = new Dog();
        Dog b = new Dog();
        Dog c = new Dog();
        Coyote d = new Coyote();
        Dog e = new Dog();
        Fox f = new Fox();
        Dog g = new Dog();
        Cat h = new Cat();
        Ferret i = new Ferret();
        Groundhog j = new Groundhog();

        Animal[] animalArray = new Animal[10];
        animalArray[0] = a;
        animalArray[1] = b;
        animalArray[2] = c;
        animalArray[3] = d;
        animalArray[4] = e;
        animalArray[5] = f;
        animalArray[6] = g;
        animalArray[7] = h;
        animalArray[8] = i;
        animalArray[9] = j;



        for(int ii = 0; ii<animalArray.length; ii++){
            if (animalArray[ii] instanceof Coyote || animalArray[ii] instanceof Fox){
                animalArray[ii] = new Dog();
            }
        }
}
```

If you include the below code in the public static void main method, you can run the method to get the following output.

```
 for(Animal animal: animalArray){
            System.out.println(animal.getClass());
        }
```

Output (where 'Test' is the package name):

```
class Test.Dog
class Test.Dog
class Test.Dog
class Test.Dog
class Test.Dog
class Test.Dog
class Test.Dog
class Test.Cat
class Test.Ferret
class Test.Groundhog
```

Comment: No problem, also checkout the ListIterator in Java which can do a similar job with Lists for when you don't know the exact number of items.